# SSIS Package working in BI Studio but not working in SQLServer 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis, data-import

I have the SSIS package which iterates all excel files in the particular folder and import rows into the SQL 2008 database.  I use 4 Package Scope Variables for files and folders paths.

[image]

I could run the package and import all data in excel files if I run the package in BI Studio.

But when I move the package and set up the job in the SQL 2008 server, I could not run the package and it shows me the following message.

Executed as user: xxxxx Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility  Version 10.0.4000.0 for 32-bit.   Started:  16:19:23  Error: 2011-05-26 16:19:23.53     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: PCounter Connection manager "Excel Connection Manager"     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft JET Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80004005  **Description: "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file ''.  It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data.".**  End Error  Error: 2011-05-26 16:19:23.53     Code: 0xC020801C     Source: Data Flow Task Excel Source [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBHin.jpg)     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.  The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager "Excel Connection Manager" failed with error code 0xC0202009.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.  End Error  Error: 2011-05-26 16:19:23.53     Code: 0xC0047017     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: component "Excel Source" (1) failed validation and returned error code 0xC020801C.  End Error  Error: 2011-05-26 16:19:23.53     Code: 0xC004700C     Source: Data Flow Task SSIS.Pipeline     Description: One or more component failed validation.  End Error  Error: 2011-05-26 16:19:23.53     Code: 0xC0024107     Source: Data Flow Task      Description: There were errors during task validation.  End Error  DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  16:19:23  Finished: 16:19:23  Elapsed:  0.547 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.

I am sure that the files are not opened by anyone and my SSIS Proxy account do has the permission to access that folder.  It still shows me this error however I tried.

Please give me suggestions.

Comment: I run it as the SQL Job Under SQL Server Agent

Comment: You can also use a tool like http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655 to see if any other process has their finger on the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a variable to set the excel file via your Excel Connection Manager. Unless you have DelayValidation set to true at the **package** level, the connection manager will fail when it can't find the file you originally specified when you set up the Excel Connection Manger. Try setting DelayValidation on both the package and the connection manager to **true** - or make sure that the file you used to set up the connection manager is accessible by your sql server/sql agent account.